# How to remove Index indicators with VerticalPageTabViewStyle?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, watchos, swiftui-tabview

How to remove Index indicators with **VerticalPageTabViewStyle**?

watchOS 10, Xcode 15, SwiftUI 5

```
struct PageTwo: View {
    
    @Binding var showIndicator: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            TabView {
                setRemindersPage()
                ReminderPage()
            }
            .tabViewStyle(VerticalPageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: showIndicator ? .always : .never))
        }
    }
}
```

Errors:

***Argument passed to call that takes no arguments**

***Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'always'**

–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

This works perfectly with **PageTabViewStyle** but not with **VerticalPageViewStyle**.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Question should be more clear now.